# Send ajax request on browser window closed

Tags: javascript

I want to send an ajax request only when the browser window closes not on refresh or reload. I am using this code.

```js
DisplayExit = function() {  
     simpleAjaxReq("formatter_main.php",'file_close' , 'true');  
};
window.onbeforeunload = DisplayExit;
```

This works when closing the browser window but also execute the code when the page reloads, is there a way for this code to only works on close not reload.

Comment: How is this answered, the question you are directing me towards is also using the same function which also fire when i refresh the browser i wanted to limit it to only when the browser window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function onload as well to disable it similar to below sample

```
     window.onload(function()
       {
     response.sendRedirect(url);
        // or     
         simpleAjaxReq("formatter_main.php",'file_close' , 
          'false');
         }
```

Comment: This will only execute the function simple ajax request when the window is closed not when it refreshes?